# JSON object on ajax respond not available

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a JSON object comming from a AJAX request.

When I do console.log(response); I see my object in the console. But if I do `console.log(response.mostSearched);` I get `undefined`, why?

I copied the object from the devTools console and put in the javascript like `var obj = {...etc};` then I did `console.log(obj.mostSearched);` and that works good.

What am I missing why not from `console.log(response);` ?

My Ajax request:

```
    var req = new Request({
        method: 'post',
        url: stats_ajax_cal,
        data: {
            'itemSelect': itemSelect,
            'type_of_graph': type_of_graph,
            'dateFrom': dateFrom,
            'dateTo': dateTo,
        },
        onSuccess: function(response) {
            console.log(response); // looks good
            var obj = response;
            console.log('***');
            console.log(obj); // looks good
            console.log(obj.mostSearched); // undefined

        }
    }).send();
```

My object:

```
{
    "mostSearched": {
        "title": "Most serached houses",
        "colNames": [],
        "rowNames": {
            "21": 1,
            "10": 2,
            "76": 1,
            "20": 1,
            "23": 1,
            "13": 3,
            "18": 1
        }
    },
    "timeOfDay": "",
    "averagePrice": 5904.8,
    "averageDuration": 0.6,
    "searchedDays": {
        "2013-12-21": 1,
        "2013-12-22": 1,
        "2013-12-23": 1,
        "2013-12-24": 1,
        "2013-12-25": 1,
        "2013-12-26": 1,
        "2013-12-27": 1,
        "2013-11-16": 2,
        "2013-11-17": 2,
        "2013-11-18": 2,
        "2013-11-19": 2,
        "2013-11-20": 2,
        "2013-11-21": 2,
        "2013-11-22": 2,
        "2013-11-23": 2,
        "2013-11-24": 2,
        "2013-11-25": 2,
        "2013-11-26": 2,
        "2013-11-27": 2,
        "2013-11-28": 2,
        "2013-11-29": 2,
        "2013-09-06": 4,
        "2013-09-07": 4,
        "2013-09-08": 4,
        "2013-09-09": 4,
        "2013-09-10": 4,
        "2013-09-11": 4,
        "2013-09-12": 1,
        "2013-10-07": 3,
        "2013-10-08": 3,
        "2013-10-09": 3,
        "2013-10-10": 3,
        "2013-10-11": 3,
        "2013-10-12": 3
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the JavaScript that processes this? What HTTP headers are included with the response?

Comment: @Quentin, updated with JS.

Comment: Does `var obj = JSON.parse(response);` fix your problem?

Comment: @fbynite, that was what I didn't do, lol... thanks. Please post a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the response string using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
```